# Como hacer que history.back() cargue la posición inicial de la pagina HTML

Tags: javascript, html5

actualmente en un botón uso un history.back() para recargar la misma pagina

```
<a href="javascript:history.back()">Volver</a>
```

Lamentablente history.back() no me carga en el inicio de la pagina, sino la posición donde estaba el boton.

Sabrían como hacer que el history.back() cargue el inicio de la pagina?

Antes:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Buscando lograr:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ese es el comportamiento del history.back... lo que puedes hacer es que al cargar una página compruebe si estás en la parte superior y si no, haga scroll al top.

Comment: Ese es el plan pero sigo buscando como hacerlo.

Comment: El addEvent tampoco funciona y en lo respecta lo otro que dijiste, seguiré investigando como lo hice antes de preguntar por stackflow, no estés asumiendo cosas para desahogarte en la red Benito

Answer (score 0):

Pero `history.back()` no es para recargar, es para volver, es más eso justo es lo que pones en tu link.

Si te refieres a simplemente hacer un reload de la página actual, lo puedes hacer fácilmente con el método `reload()`.

`window.location.reload()`

Eso provocará que el navegador muestre de nuevo la página actual, haciendo una recarga de la misma en la que te encuentres en este momento.

Otra alternativa para recargar la página actual es cambiar el location.

Si le pones al `location` el mismo valor que tienes en el `location`, simplemente te recargará esa página actual.

`window.location = window.location`

---

Si quieres ir al inicio (top) de la pagina usa algo como

`window.scrollTo(0, 0);`

```js
 function scrollToTop() {
            window.scrollTo(0, 0);
        }
```

```css
.scroll {
            height: 1000px;
            background-color: lightgreen;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 
<head>
    <title>To the top of the page</title>
</head>
 
<body>
    <h1 style="color: teal">
        Banner
    </h1>
 
    <p class="scroll">Contenido</p>
 
    <a href="#" onclick="scrollToTop()">
        Subir (Link)
    </a>
    
    <button onclick="scrollToTop()">
        Subir (Botón)
    </button>
</body>
 
</html>
```

Comment: El history.back en caso de no encontrar una pagina anterior se llama a si misma. También prové el window.location.reload() pero da el mismo resultado, se ubica en la ultima posicion que estube antes y no al inicio de la pagina HTML

Comment: Me acabo de dar cuenta si estaba usando el window.location.reload(), aun así no recarga en el inicio de la pagina

Comment: @prox agregué otro ejemplo.

Comment: me di cuenta, el tema es que es sea en el href o en un archivo js si muevo la posición de la pagina al inicio y luego recargó la pagina esto genera una molestia visual, queria ver si había una forma de poder pasarle al reload() alguna parámetro para pasarle la localización de la pagina, o quizas otra función que te permita recargar la pagina de forma mas personalizada.